# Swift Codable with Generics, holding common data from responses

Tags: ios, swift, generics, codable, jsondecoder

I will try to explain what I want to do in a best possible way, just like I tried while Googling for the last couple of days.

My application is communicating with few different APIs, but let's consider responses from one API first. Response from each endpoint holds some 'common parameters', such as statuses or error messages, and a single object or array of objects that we're mostly interested in, it brings important data, we might want to encode it, store it, put it to Realm, CoreData, etc.

For Example, response with single object:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "messages": [
        "message1",
        "message2"
    ]
    "data": {
        OBJECT we're interested in.
    }
}
```

Or, response with an array of objects:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "messages": [
        "message1",
        "message2"
    ]
    "data": [
        {
            OBJECT we're interested in.
        },
        {
            OBJECT we're interested in.
        }
    ]
}
```

Okay. That is simple enough, easy to understand.

Now, I want to write a single "Root" Object that will hold 'common parameters', or `status`, `response_code` and `messages` and have another, property for a specific object (or array of objects) that we're interested in.

---

**Inheritance**
First approach was creating a Root Object, like this:

```swift
class Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let response_code: Int
    let messages: [String]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, response_code, messages
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code) ?? ""
        response_code = try container?.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .error) ?? 0
        messages = try container?.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .key)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {}
}
```

Once I have this Root Object, I could create specific object that inherits from this Root object and pass my specific object in JSONDecoder, and there, I have a nice solution. But, **this solution is failing for arrays**. 
Maybe for someone it doesn't, **but I can not stress enough how much I don't want to make additional 'plural' object that only exists to hold an array of Objects**, like:

```swift
class Objects: Root {
    let objects: [Object]
    // Code that decodes array of "Object" from "data" key
}

struct Object: Codable {
    let property1
    let property2
    let property3
    // Code that decodes all properties of Object
}
```

It doesn't look clean, it requires separate object that simply holds an array, it creates issues with storing to Realm in some cases due to inheritance, it **above all** produces less readable code.

---

**Generics**
My 2nd idea was to try something with Generics, so I made [a little something like this](https://youtu.be/TLGWQfK-6DY?t=8):

```swift
struct Root<T: Codable>: Codable  {
    let status: String
    let response_code: Int
    let messages: [String]?
    let data: T?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, response_code, messages, data
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code) ?? ""
        response_code = try container?.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .error) ?? 0
        messages = try container?.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .key)
        data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .data)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {}
}
```

With this, I was able to pass both Single Objects and Arrays of Objects to JSONDecoder like this:

```swift
let decodedValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root<Object>.self, from: data)
// or
let decodedValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root<[Object]>.self, from: data)
```

and this is pretty nice. I can grab the struct I need in .data property of Root struct and use it as I like, as single object or as array of objects. I can store it easily, manipulate however I want without restraints inheritance brings in upper example.
Where this idea fails for my case is when I want to access 'common properties' in some place that isn't sure what T was set to.
This being a simplified explanation of what's actually happening in my app, I will extend it a bit to explain where this Generic solution doesn't work for me and finally ask my question.

---

**Problem and Question**
As mentioned at the top, application works with 3 APIs, and all 3 APIs have different `Root` structs, and of course, a lot of different "sub-structs" - to name them. I have a single place, single `APIResponse` object in application that goes back to the UI part of the application in which I extract 1 readable error from `decoded value`, `decoded value` being that 'sub-struct', being any of my "specific Objects", `Car`, `Dog`, `House`, `Phone`.
With **Inheritance** solution, I was able to do something like this:

```swift
struct APIResponse <T> {
    var value: T? {
        didSet {
            extractErrorDescription()
        }
    }
    var errorDescription: String? = "Oops."

    func extractErrorDescription() {
        if let responseValue = value as? Root1, let error = responseValue.errors.first {
            self.errorDescription = error
        }
        else if let responseValue = value as? Root2 {
            self.errorDescription = responseValue.error
        }
        else if let responseValue = value as? Root3 {
            self.errorDescription = responseValue.message
        }
    }
}
```

but with **Generics** solution, I am unable to do that. If I try to write this same code with `Root1` or `Root2` or `Root3` being constructed as shown in **Generics** example like this:

```swift
func extractErrorDescription() {
    if let responseValue = value as? Root1, let error = responseValue.errors.first {
        self.errorDescription = error
    }
}
```

I will get error saying `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'Root1'` and here, where I'm trying to extract the error, I don't know which sub-struct was passed to Root1. Was it `Root1<Dog>` or `Root1<Phone>` or `Root1<Car>` - I don't know how to figure out, and I obviously need to know in order to find out if value is `Root1` or `Root2` or `Root3`.

**Solution I am looking for is a solution that would allow me to distinguish between `Root` objects with Generics solution shown above, or a solution that allows me to architecture decoding in some completely different way, keeping in mind everything I wrote, especially ability to avoid 'plural' objects**

**If JSON doesn't pass JSON validator, please ignore, it was handwritten just for sake of this quesion*
***If written Code doesn't run, please ignore, this is more of an architectural question than how to make some piece of code compile.*

Comment: wouldn't you need to do something like `if let responseValue = value as? Root1<T>` so that it knows the type to cast to?

Comment: for the inheritance route you could make each conform to a common protocol and have a computed property on each to return the error message

Comment: @Scriptable in your first comment yes, I would need `if let responseValue = value as? Root1<T>` but I don't know what `T` is in that place, and can be any of 20 or 30 structures that work with `Root1`. If I check against each, 1 will work and I will normally access my "common properties", but that's not really the way to go.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for here is a protocol.

```
protocol ErrorProviding {
    var error: String? { get }
}
```

I'm intentionally changing `errorDescription` to `error` because that seems to be what you have in your root types (but you could definitely rename things here).

Then APIResponse requires that:

```
struct APIResponse<T: ErrorProviding> {
    var value: T?
    var error: String? { value?.error }
}
```

And then each root type with special handling implements the protocol:

```
extension Root1: ErrorProviding {
    var error: String? { errors.first }
}
```

But simple root types that already have the right shape can just declare conformance with no extra implementation required.

```
extension Root2: ErrorProviding {}
```

Assuming you want more than just `error`, you could make this `APIPayload` rather than `ErrorProviding` and add any other common requirements.

As a side note, your code will be simpler if you just use Decodable rather than using Codable with empty `encode` methods. A type shouldn't conform to Encodable if it can't really be encoded.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks Rob. I understand your Idea about APIPayload too - agree on Decodable. Could you let me know what you meant by "but you could definitely rename things here", I mean, what except for 'errorDescription'?
And I publicly admit that I need to go back to Protocols and revisit them, they were rising while I was doing more 'managing' and less 'coding'.

Comment: By "rename things" I just meant that it was fine if one layer had `error` and one had `errorDescription`; you'd just have to write more bridging code in that case. Nothing really important.

Comment: Thanks Rob, one more thought I had. With this **Generics** approach, could I somehow (if needed, in case of some object update, where API returns only `status`, `response_code` and `messages`) decode ONLY 'common properties'? Like, could I somehow do something like `try JSONDecoder().decode(Root<Void>.self, from: data)`? Theoretically, have that type optional? I can think of a 'hack' by creating some `VoidCodable` struct with no properties, but wondering if there is something better?

Comment: Yeah; I originally wrote exactly that. I wouldn't call it `VoidCodable`. I'd call it `struct Ignore: Decodable {}`, but yeah, that's fine and it's exactly what you mean.